# Android: View.animate() not working with custom background for ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

In a recent Android [DevBytes video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ7PTe7QMQM) it was explained how you could animate a button using `Interpolators` and the `View.animate()` method to make it look more cartoony.

Code below:

```
public class LiveButton extends Activity {

    DecelerateInterpolator sDecelerator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    OvershootInterpolator sOvershooter = new OvershootInterpolator(10f);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overshoot);

        final Button clickMeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickMe);
        clickMeButton.animate().setDuration(200);

        clickMeButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    clickMeButton.animate().setInterpolator(sDecelerator).
                            scaleX(.7f).scaleY(.7f);
                } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    clickMeButton.animate().setInterpolator(sOvershooter).
                            scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

So in my own app I tried doing this with an `ImageButton` which works fine. But whenever I change the default button background to my own image the effect is lost.

I change the background of the `ImageButton` like this:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(resID);
```

I think this changes the `android:src` and not the `android:background` so maybe that's why it's not working? Any idea what I should do here?

Note: changing the `android:background` inside XML to my own image DOES work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling the animate method of the parent view of the `ImageButton` like this:

```
((View)imageButtonView.getParent()).animate().setInterpolator(sDecelerator).
                                scaleX(.7f).scaleY(.7f);
```